# My plt animation doesn't work: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'canvas'"

Tags: matplotlib, animation, canvas, figure, nonetype

I'm trying to simulate the segregation process in a city for a school project. I've managed to plot the city when initialized and after segregation, but I don't manage to create the animation showing the city's inhabitants moving to show the evolution.
I have two methods in my Ville class (I'm coding in French) that should make the animation together.

```
def afficher(self, inclure_satisfaction=False, inclure_carte_categories=False, size=5):
    carte = self.carte_categories(inclure_satisfaction=inclure_satisfaction)
    if inclure_carte_categories:
        print("Voici la carte des catégories (à titre de vérification)")
        print(carte)
    
    mat_rs = masked_array(carte, carte!=1.5)
    mat_ri = masked_array(carte, carte!=1)
    mat_bs = masked_array(carte, carte!=2.5)
    mat_bi = masked_array(carte, carte!=2)

    plt.figure(figsize=(size, size))
    affichage_rs = plt.imshow(mat_rs, cmap=cmap_rs)
    affichage_ri = plt.imshow(mat_ri, cmap=cmap_ri)
    affichage_bs = plt.imshow(mat_bs, cmap=cmap_bs)
    affichage_bi = plt.imshow(mat_bi, cmap=cmap_bi)
    return plt.figure()
```

(this function plot the map by first getting an array from the method *carte_categories* in function of the category of each inhabitant and then getting an array for each value to plot)

```
def resoudre2(self):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    list_of_artists = []
    while self.habitants_insatisfaits != []:
        self.demenagement_insatisfait_aleatoire()
        list_of_artists.append([self.afficher(inclure_satisfaction=True)])
    ani = ArtistAnimation(fig, list_of_artists, interval=200, blit=True)
    return ani
```

(habitants_insatisfaits is a list that contains the "insatisfied inhabitants": there are two few people of their category around them, so they want to move somewhere else; so resoudre means solve, and this function loops until all the inhabitants are satisfied where they are (and this way the society is mechanically segregated)

The initialized city looks like this [initialized city](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEesf.png) (dark colors for insatisfied inhabitants), and the segregated city looks like that [segregated city](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmM07.png).

But when I enter

```
a = ville1.resoudre2(compter=True)
```

I don't get an animation but only this error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:211: RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:206: RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 196, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 951, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1533, in _init_draw
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'canvas'
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py:452: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.
  dv = np.float64(self.norm.vmax) - np.float64(self.norm.vmin)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py:459: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.
  a_min = np.float64(newmin)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py:464: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.
  a_max = np.float64(newmax)
<string>:6: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/colors.py:993: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.
  data = np.asarray(value)
```

(first problem) and then every map (corresponding to each step of the segregating city) is plotted (second problem; see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NjsE.png)). And when I try to type

```
print(a)
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(a.to_html5_video())
```

to plot the animation, I only get

```
<matplotlib.animation.ArtistAnimation object at 0x7f4cd376bfd0>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-20-d7ca1fcdadb6> in <module>()
      1 print(a)
      2 from IPython.display import HTML
----> 3 HTML(a.to_html5_video())

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in _init_draw(self)
   1531         # Flush the needed figures
   1532         for fig in figs:
-> 1533             fig.canvas.draw_idle()
   1534 
   1535     def _pre_draw(self, framedata, blit):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'canvas'
```

So I don't understand why I get this error and not just my animation...
Thank you for your help, it's the first time I ask questions here so don't hesitate if you need more details about my code! :)

Nathan

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, downgrading Matplotlib fixed the issue for me.

`pip install matplotlib==3.5.1`